# Chrome Extension: Background script only functioning correctly for the first time

Tags: javascript, audio, google-chrome-extension, mediarecorder

I am working on a chrome extension that receives the audio from the microphone and the current tab. It is working fine for the first time but the script is not running correctly (It works but not as expected) in the subsequent runs.

Here is the code for my background(not persistent) script:

```
const audioContext = new AudioContext();
const destination = audioContext.createMediaStreamDestination();

const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

let chunks = [],
  tabStream,
  micStream,
  tabAudio,
  micAudio,
  output,
  audioConfig,
  text = '',
  micable = true,
  paused = false;

const constraints = {
  audio: true,
};

function getTabAudio() {
  chrome.tabCapture.capture(constraints, (_stream) => {
    // keep playing the audio in the background
    const audio = new Audio();
    audio.srcObject = _stream;
    audio.play();

    tabStream = _stream;
    tabAudio = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(tabStream);
    tabAudio.connect(destination);

    output = new MediaStream();
    output.addTrack(destination.stream.getAudioTracks()[0]);

    recorder = new MediaRecorder(output);

    recorder.start();

    recorder.ondataavailable = (e) => {
      chunks.push(e.data);
      // call download when recorder state is inactive
      if (recorder.state == 'inactive') download();
    };
  });
}

// get mic audio
function getMicAudio() {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then((mic) => {
    micStream = mic;
    micAudio = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(micStream);
    micAudio.connect(destination);

    // get tab audio
    getTabAudio();
  });
}

// start recording the stream
function startRecord() {
  getMicAudio();
}

// stop record -> stop all the tracks
function stopRecord() {
  recorder.stop();

  micStream.getTracks().forEach((t) => t.stop());
  tabStream.getTracks().forEach((t) => t.stop());
  output.getTracks().forEach((t) => t.stop());

  micable = true;
  chunks = [];
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  switch (request.type) {
    case 'record':
      startRecord();
      break;
    case 'stop':
      stopRecord();
      break;
    case 'pause':
      pauseResumeRecord();
      break;
    case 'mute':
      muteMic();
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
});
```

To make it work again, I have to refresh the current tab and extension from the `chrome://extenions` page.

- I am not using any `onInstalled` listeners.

Any help is highly appreciated! 
 Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I solved it finally! 
The answer is to **reload the background script each time the recorder was stopped**. This way the background script variables will be reset to their default values and the script will work as expected.

Here is the code to reset the background script:

```
chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().window.location.reload();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please review the background page console logs.... Probably there are errors there that you to solve...

To do it
Write click your extension icon at the top corner of chrome... Manage extensions... Enable developer mode at the top right corner... Open inspect views background page

Comment: Actually, the console is clear there. No errors.

Comment: I feel the problem is in how I am handling the audio streams. After running the extension for the second time I am not getting any streams.